# Delete string from textbox,shapes etc that may be grouped

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, powerpoint

This will remove the texts from shapes or textboxes but not from grouped textboxes or shapes.

How can I modify the code below to suit my need ?

What I want is simple remove the string `strf` and `"(" & strf & ")"` present any where in the ppt. But this seems to ignore the grouped objects.

```
       For Each Sld In PP.Slides
            For Each Shp In Sld.Shapes
                With Shp
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "(" & strf & ")", "")
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, strf, "")
                     Debug.Print Sld.Name, .Name, .TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                End With
            Next Shp
        Next Sld
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/472302-grouped-shapes-visual-basic-applications.html) by MrExcel MVP.

This loops through each sub items in the group which I wanted essentially.

```
        For Each Sld In PP.Slides
            For Each Shp In Sld.Shapes
                With Shp
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "(" & strf & ")", "")
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, strf, "")
                     Debug.Print Sld.Name, .Name, .TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                End With

                For Each Shp1 In Shp.GroupItems
                With Shp1
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "(" & strf & ")", "")
                    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, strf, "")
                    Debug.Print Sld.Name, .Name, .TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                End With
                Next

            Next Shp

        Next Sld
```